# PySimpleGUI popup_get_folder default_path

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, path, pysimplegui

i have a problem with popup_get_folder, PySimpleGUI. i can't set default path, I get error:
popup() got an unexpected keyword argument 'default_path', what can i do? popup_get_folder() has an argument "default_path"

```
if event == "BUTTON":
        dirfiles = sg.popup_get_folder('Please enter a folder name')
        sg.popup('Results', 'The value returned from popup_get_folder', dirfiles, default_path="C:/Users/User/Desktop/NEWFOLDER")
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error message `error: popup() got an unexpected keyword argument 'default_path'`

Python tells us the function that's causing the error: `popup`

It also tells us what the error is: you passed in the argument `default_path` when this is not something that the `popup` function is expecting.

To find out what arguments you can pass to the `popup` function, you can look at the documentation for the library: https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#high-level-api-calls-popups

```
popup(args=*<1 or N object>,
    title = None,
    button_color = None,
    background_color = None,
    text_color = None,
    button_type = 0,
    auto_close = False,
    auto_close_duration = None,
    custom_text = (None, None),
    non_blocking = False,
    icon = None,
    line_width = None,
    font = None,
    no_titlebar = False,
    grab_anywhere = False,
    keep_on_top = None,
    location = (None, None),
    relative_location = (None, None),
    any_key_closes = False,
    image = None,
    modal = True)
```

Comment: but popup_get_folder has argumtent defult_path

popup_get_folder(message,
    title = None,
    default_path = "",   ...)

Comment: Yes, `popup_get_folder` has argument `default_path`, but not for `popup`. Maybe you use it in wrong call.